# List of pragma in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pragma

I know that pragma is pragmatic information about how to interpret the code that follows. However, I couldn't find a list of pragmas in JavaScript other than `use strict`.

Can someone tell me the list of pragma available in JavaScript?

Comment: `use strict;` is the only one I know of for Javascript.  I don't think there are any more.  I assume you've searched for this before asking?

Comment: @Archer FF specific `"use asm";`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko My new thing learned - thanks.  I *never* use FF so I wouldn't know of a FF-specific directive.

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko, are there any further pragmas available other than these 2?

Comment: Atleast all I am aware of :).  There are some proposals to add more pragmas https://github.com/tc39/proposal-modules-pragma. As of current [spec Directive Prologue](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#directive-prologue) it describes only 1 directive `"use strict;"` but allows implementation specific ones.